# When do we need to include comma after as?

Tags: commas

Might someone be able to help explain why we it is not necessary to include a comma next to as.

1: Studies have found that those students who major in philosophy often do better than students from other majors in both verbal reasoning and analytical writing, as measured by standardized test scores.

2: Studies have found that those students who major in philosophy often do better than students from other majors in both verbal reasoning and analytical writing as measured by standardized test scores.

Can I explain the comma is not necessary by using sentence 3 as an example?

3: Studies have found that writing is good for students as measured by standardized test scores?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special about the word "as", relating to commas.  You use a comma in example 1 because it's a **long sentence with multiple clauses**, and the comma helps the reader to understand what is being said, ie to **parse the sentence**.

In example 3, the comma would also increase the readability of the sentence, but because it's shorter then the omission of the comma makes less of a difference.  It would still be better with a comma.

In other words, 2 and 3 are both missing the comma, but because 2 is longer and more complicated, the missing comma has a larger negative effect.